# Is there any folder synchronization service?

Tags: webapp-rec, synchronization, online-storage

I know you can synchronize folders using online storage services, but is there any of such sites that offer a synchronization tool? I would like to keep my folder identical to its cloud copy, in more than one computer.

If I delete a file from computer A, it should be deleted both in the cloud and then in the computer B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dropbox](http://getdropbox.com) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Dropbox makes you put all synced data in a single folder, and more importantly, current versions of the client (but not forum builds) force you to sync everything in that folder rather than choosing specific subfolders.  Mesh has neither restriction, so I'd stick with mesh until you exceed the storage limit.

Comment: +1 for dropbox. It has versioning too, Live Mesh does not.

Comment: @crosstalk: You can solve the "outside of the Dropbox folder" problem by using a symlink. See: http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders . It's also a planned enhancement for a future update. See https://www.dropbox.com/help/12

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Live Mesh](https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx) does this, and it's free. I've used it for sync'ing large projects of source code between my office and home office, and it worked very nicely. It operates via the "cloud" (i.e. it gives you free online storage), and you can specify which devices you want to connect to that cloud repository.

Comment: Heh, love the down vote on a question that is 7.5 years old - for any of you too young to remember Live Mesh was the precursor to OneDrive.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu one give this feature. https://one.ubuntu.com/